# Horizontal and vertical positioning of text in thumb index

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, positioning, thumb-index

I am trying to ensure that the letters in thumb index are centered both horizontally and vertically and have a trouble adjusting the size of the thumb index or setting centering within it.
Theoretically, for horizontal alignment `eventxtindent` and `oddtxtexdent` should help position the letters but the trouble is with varying width of the letters - they cannot all be LE, RO aligned and end up centered. I am trying to avoid centering each letter manually...

With vertical alignment, I am somewhat clueless. Whatever I do the letters end up slightly lowered in the thumb rectangle and I want them exactly centered.

```
%!TEX TS -program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=190mm, paperheight=280mm, textwidth=170mm,  textheight=263mm, 
            top=14mm, bottom=22mm, inner=14mm, outer=19mm, headsep=3mm, headheight=6mm, footskip=12mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[width=12mm, height=9mm, distance=0.5mm, eventxtindent=7mm, oddtxtexdent=2.5mm, topthumbmargin=22mm, bottomthumbmargin=12mm]{thumbs}

\usepackage{lipsum}  


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{A}
\addthumb{A}{A}{white}{gray}
\lipsum
\chapter{B}
\addthumb{B}{B}{white}{gray}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```